# How can I use grep to search for years from 1900 to 2100?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

How can I use grep to search for years from 1900 to 2100?

For example, if I have a variable with `20123320` I want to print `2012`.

Comment: Hmm, what is the pattern of your variable? Is it always like YYYYMMDD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funny ways **using bash** (`sh` users beware!):

If you want to match and print all these years that appear at the beginning of lines in a file `file`:

```
printf "^%s\n" {1900..2100} | grep -of - file
```

If you have a variable `variable` that contains `20123320`:

```
variable=20123320
printf "^%s\n" {1900..2100} | grep -of - <(echo "$variable")
```

Now please detail a little bit more what you want to do exactly so that we can give you the most appropriate answer.

**Edit.** As I see other answers using other tools than [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) here's a 100% [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) solution:

```
variable="20123320"
# take the first 4 characters of variable:
year="${variable:0:4}"
# check that year is an integer and that it falls into the given range
if [[ "$year" =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]] && (( 1900<=year && year<=2100)); then
    echo "$year"
else
    # Do whatever you want here
    echo "You dumbo, I couldn't find a valid year in your string"
fi
```

Comment: Note : this solution require `bash`

Comment: @sputnick the good thing is that this question is also tagged bash `:-)`

Comment: I know, but your answer will be (possibly) read by other shells users who will discover with surprise that "this doesn't work"

Comment: For sh, you could replace `{1900..2100}` by BACKTICKseq 1900 2100BACKTICK -- assuming that you have the `seq` command. (Replace BACKTICK by the backtick character.)

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="4 "}{if($1~/^[0-9]+$/&&$1>=1900&&$1<=2100)print $1}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
echo "$var" | grep -Eo '\b(((19|20)[0-9][0-9])|2100)'
```

Or see my [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) solution, since I think using `regex` here is not the best path.

Comment: Mostly works if it's at the beginning of a line.  That wasn't specified, though.   Also isn't specified whether there are other things, particularly numbers like 195... and either way, this wouldn't print just the year; it'd print the whole line.

Comment: That covers about a third of the concerns.  :)

Comment: Bad luck, you're also matching `2100`, `2099`, etc. `:-(`

Comment: Why bad luck ? This is what I want : print every dates between (including) range 1900 - 2100. AFAIK, that's what's OP asked.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I misread the question, but you'll match `2199` then. Still bad luck `:-(`

Answer (score 0):

[grep](/questions/tagged/grep) is not the better tool to do this, Perl will be more suitable, easier & robust to test numeric ranges :

```
echo "$var" | perl -lne '
    $year = substr($_, 0, 4);
    print $year if $year <= 2100 && $year >= 1900 && $year =~ /^\d+$/
'
```

or with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) with the same logic :

```
echo "$var" | awk '
{
    year = substr($0, 0, 4)
    if (year <= 2100 && year >= 1900 && $1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/) {
        print year
    }
}'
```

Comment: awk will print `201x` if the string is `"201x3320"`

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using `grep` for this, you can.

I'll assume that you want to match a variable that starts with 4 digits in in the range 1900 to 2100, and you want to print just those 4 digits.

```
echo "$var" | grep -Eo '^(((19|20)[0-9][0-9])|2100)'
```

This ignores whatever may follow those first 4 digits (because I can't think of a way to check the rest of the string without printing it).

But `grep` is not the obvious tool for this job, nor is a regular expression the best tool for matching a range of numbers. For example, if you needed to match numbers from 1950 to 2100, the regular expression would have to be substantially different.

Personally, I'd use Perl:

```
echo "$var" | perl -ne 'if (/^(\d{4})\d{4}$/ and $1 >= 1900 and $1 <= 2100) { print "$1\n" }'
```

This checks that `$var` contains exactly 8 decimal digits. If you want to check that they make up a valid date, you'll need some more code.

You could also do it fairly cleanly in awk, which might be a bit faster.